# Why is my implementation of binary search very inefficient?

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search

I am doing a Python exercise to search a `word` from a given sorted `wordlist`, containing more than 100,000 words.

When using `bisect_left` from the Python [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html), it is very efficient, but using the binary method created by myself is very inefficient. Could anyone please clarify why？

This is the searching method using the Python `bisect` module:

```
def in_bisect(word_list, word):
    """Checks whether a word is in a list using bisection search.

    Precondition: the words in the list are sorted

    word_list: list of strings
    word: string
    """
    i = bisect_left(word_list, word)
    if i != len(word_list) and word_list[i] == word:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

My implementation is really very inefficient (don't know why):

```
def my_bisect(wordlist,word):
    """search the given word in a wordlist using
    bisection search, also known as binary search
    """
    if len(wordlist) == 0:
        return False
    if len(wordlist) == 1:
        if wordlist[0] == word:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    if word in wordlist[len(wordlist)/2:]:
        return True

    return my_bisect(wordlist[len(wordlist)/2:],word)
```

Comment: Because you aren't actually using a binary search?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I tried to implement the binary search, in which I search the beginning half, if not in beginning half, I search another half

Comment: The problem here is that you're making copies of the list on every level, this will dwarf any benefits you gain from doing the binary search. Try using only indexes to separate out which part to search in.

Comment: Additionally, you're doing "if word in xxx", which will do a loop and comparison. This is not a binary search at all.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen, I now understand, thanks for the hint, yes, I didn't use the binary search at all. I should compare the word in the middle with the searching word before selecting which half. Thanks!

Comment: @bean and you're currently *only* searching the first half.

Comment: `if word in wordlist[len(wordlist)/2:]` will make Python search through half of your `wordlist`, which is kinda defeating the purpose of writing a binary search at all. Note that binary search will only work on a sorted list.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen, how to use only indexes to separate out which part to search in, could you give me more hint? As slice also copies the list which eats a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if word in wordlist[len(wordlist)/2:]
```

will make Python search through half of your `wordlist`, which is kinda defeating the purpose of writing a binary search in the first place. Also, you are not splitting the list in half correctly. The strategy for binary search is to cut the search space in half each step, and then only apply the same strategy to the half which your `word` *could* be in. In order to know which half is the right one to search, it is critical that the `wordlist` is sorted. Here's a sample implementation which keeps track of the number of calls needed to verify whether a `word` is in `wordlist`.

```
import random

numcalls = 0
def bs(wordlist, word):
    # increment numcalls
    print('wordlist',wordlist)
    global numcalls
    numcalls += 1

    # base cases
    if not wordlist:
        return False
    length = len(wordlist)
    if length == 1:
        return wordlist[0] == word

    # split the list in half
    mid = int(length/2) # mid index
    leftlist = wordlist[:mid]
    rightlist = wordlist[mid:]
    print('leftlist',leftlist)
    print('rightlist',rightlist)
    print()

    # recursion
    if word < rightlist[0]:
        return bs(leftlist, word) # word can only be in left list
    return bs(rightlist, word) # word can only be in right list

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
wl = sorted(random.sample(alphabet, 10))
print(bs(wl, 'm'))
print(numcalls)
```

I included some `print` statements so you can see what is going on. Here are two sample outputs. First: `word` is in the `wordlist`:

```
wordlist ['b', 'c', 'g', 'i', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'r', 's', 'v']
leftlist ['b', 'c', 'g', 'i', 'l']
rightlist ['m', 'n', 'r', 's', 'v']

wordlist ['m', 'n', 'r', 's', 'v']
leftlist ['m', 'n']
rightlist ['r', 's', 'v']

wordlist ['m', 'n']
leftlist ['m']
rightlist ['n']

wordlist ['m']
True
4
```

Second: `word` is not in the `wordlist`:

```
wordlist ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g', 'l', 'o', 'q', 't', 'x']
leftlist ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g']
rightlist ['l', 'o', 'q', 't', 'x']

wordlist ['l', 'o', 'q', 't', 'x']
leftlist ['l', 'o']
rightlist ['q', 't', 'x']

wordlist ['l', 'o']
leftlist ['l']
rightlist ['o']

wordlist ['l']
False
4
```

Note that if you double the size of the wordlist, i.e. use

```
wl = sorted(random.sample(alphabet, 20))
```

`numcalls` on average will be only one higher than for a `wordlist` of length 10, because `wordlist` has to be split in half only once more.

Comment: I copied your bs() function into my code and use it to do binary search, the speed is still much slower than using the library function, don't know why?

Comment: @bean my code creates new lists each function call, you can avoid that by adjusting the function to only look at certain indexes of the `wordlist`, instead of creating `leftlist` and `rightlist`.

Comment: yes I did use slice [len(wordlist)/2:] to only look at certain indexes of the wordlist, still doesn't work.

Comment: @bean slicing is creating a new list

Comment: thanks could you let me know how to only look at certain indexes of the wordlist then? I cannot figure out a method to do that.

Answer (score 0):

to search if a word is in a wordlist simply (python 2.7):

```
def bisect_fun(listfromfile, wordtosearch):
    bi = bisect.bisect_left(listfromfile, wordtosearch)
    if listfromfile[bi] == wordtosearch:
        return listfromfile[bi], bi
```